# Database for images

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have experience with databases, but not specifically with storing/querying images with databases.

I have no idea where to start. Could you please recommend me books that concentrate ONLY on databases for media content, that is images. Storing videos would be cool too but not essential.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to store media in the database?

Comment: I want to store information for each image. For example, the image contains people, the theme is friendship, and so on...

Answer (score 7):

Most of the time you'll just want to store a pointer to the media on a file system in the database. Then, you use the path in this field to actually retrieve the image and/or video.

Most databases have a size limit on the amount of data that can be stored in a column (I know SQL Server is 2GB, but I forget the rest off the top of my head).

Comment: Storing the path of the image, ok that makes sense. For some reason I thought you can store the image itself as part of the database file.

Comment: @user1007632 you _can_ store the image in the table, but you probably don't _want_ to. The pointer (and associated metadata) is generally the preferred way to go. In other words, use the filesystem for files and the database for data :)

Comment: @user1007632: Some database engines have built-in file systems as well for this sort of thing, but I've never personally used them.  The basic idea is that relational tables aren't designed for storing files (they _can_, but they're not optimized for it).  File systems are.  So it's a matter of using the right tool for the job.  Without a usable file system in the DBMS, stick with the host's file system.